# Autofill Range using R1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to autofill a formula using a dynamic range in Excel VBA using R1C1 referencing.

Rather than using something like this:

```
Sheets("my_sheet").Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A:"&row_count), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I have written the following:

```
Sheets("my_sheet").Cells(2, 17).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("my_sheet").Range(Cells(3, 17), Cells(row_count, 17)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This doesn't seem to work though and returns the following:

```
Run-time error '1004':
AutoFill method of Range class failed.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221841%28v=office.11%29.aspx) "The destination must include the source range."  The problem with your second equation is actually that the destination address starts below the row than the autofill reference.  You reference row 2 but the destination starts on row 3.  Change 3 to 2 and it will work.

---

Your second equation is fine but it's not equivalent to the first one.

If your first equation works you can directly replace it with this:

```
Sheets("my_sheet").Cells(2, 1).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("my_sheet").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(row_count, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

---

BTW - your first equation has an extra ':' after A2:A:

It should read like this:

```
Sheets("my_sheet").Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & row_count), Type:=xlFillDefault
```